# Why am I getting a RuntimeBinderException when returning dynamic?

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, massive

I'm using Massive and have a Members table. On my Members class I have a find method to find a member by Email:

```
   public class Members : DynamicModel
    {
        public Members(): base("TSConnection", "Members", "Id"){}

        public dynamic Find(string email)
        {
            dynamic result = new ExpandoObject();
            result.Success = false;
            try
            {
                result.Member = this.Single(where: "Email=@0", args: email);
                result.Success = result.Member != null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result.Message = ex.Message;
            }
            return result;
        }
}
```

This returns everything as expected and in a seperate unit test testing that `result.Member.Id` shows it's populated with the data.

In a seperate class, Addresses. I try to use this method to check that the user exists and to retrieve the Member.Id to use when inserting an address for the particular member:

```
 public class Addresses : DynamicModel
    {
        public Addresses() : base("TS", "Addresses", "Id") { }

        public dynamic Create(string email, string type, string address1, string address2, string city, string state, int countryId, string postcode)
        {
            var members = new Members();
            dynamic result = new ExpandoObject();
            result.Success = false;
            //var member = members.Find(email);

            result.Member = members.Single(where: "Email=@0", args: email);
            dynamic address = new ExpandoObject();

            if (result.Member != null)
            {
                address.Id = this.Insert(new {
                    MemberId = result.Member.Id,  
                    AddressTypeId = (int)AddressType.Account,
                    Address1 = address1,
                    Address2 = address2,
                    City = city,
                    State = state,
                    Country = countryId,
                    Postcode = postcode
                });
                result.Address = address.Id != 0 ? address : null;
                result.Success = address.Id != 0;
            }
            return result;
        }
}
```

On the tabbed out line which reads `var member = members.Find(email);` this is returning a RuntimeBinderException when I try to access `member.Member.Id`. I step into the code and the Find method is 'returning' the correct data but it's not being passed to the variable member. Oddly when I use the code to retrieve the user on the line below:

```
result.Member = members.Single(where: "Email=@0", args: email);
```

It works fine. Not really good for keeping things DRY though. What is going on and is there a way I can use the Find method from my Members class inside my Addresses class?

Lloyd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are returning `result`, from `Find`, which is an `ExpandoObject`. To access the `Member` in `Addresses` you need to change the code to:

```
var members = new Members();
var result = members.Find(email);
var member = result.Member;
```